# GHS2 Low Energy Bluetooth USB dongle not working on Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, bluetooth

I bought [this](https://ghs2.net/product/bluetooth-4-0-usb-adapter/) GHS2 Blueooth v4 USB dongle because it claims to work on Linux.

So far, my Pi 2 Model B doesn't recognize it. From what I can tell the drivers on the manufacturer's website (linked above) appear to be for Windows.

Are there some generic drivers one can install to try to get it working on Raspbian, (Debian for Pi)?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

I also followed all of the suggestions [here](https://fixmynix.com/bluetooth-in-linux-with-bluez-and-hcitool/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you might have lucked out there. Unless the product page explicitly says it works with the Raspberry Pi or you have found someone who has go it to work with the Pi, the chances are it is not supported.

You can however try running:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
hcitool dev
```

Followed by a reboot. Then run:

```
hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

To make the device discoverable.

As a final check try:

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman bluez python-gobject python-gobject-2
```

It installs a GUI interface among other things which allows you to control the Bluetooth module. The software is located under menu, preferences then Bluetooth adapter.

If you still can't get it to work I suggest returning it and looking through the list of [compatible Bluetooth adapters](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Bluetooth_adapters).

Comment: Thanks. Yea, I think I tried all of those packages and `hcitool` / `hciconf` as well as rebooting, so you're right - no luck. It's not just Pi tho; I tried it on an Ubuntu laptop and no luck there either. Want a free bluetooth dongle for your Windows computer?

Comment: That depends if you want to pay for the shipping ;). I might also add that the company didn't look particularly reputable judging by some of the wording on the product page and the overall design...